`screen` takes forever to execute in a certain terminal over ssh
I have a weird issue with screen where it takes 10+ seconds to execute any command, even screen -v:
$ time screen -v
Screen version 4.09.00 (GNU) 30-Jan-22

________________________________________________________
Executed in   18.86 secs    fish           external
   usr time    3.06 secs  599.00 micros    3.06 secs
   sys time   15.80 secs    0.00 micros   15.80 secs

It only happens with one terminal (integrated terminal for vscode) and only on a remote server (when connected via vscode-ssh). If I connect to the same server using any other terminal (iTerm, for example), everything is fine:
$ time screen -v
Screen version 4.09.00 (GNU) 30-Jan-22

________________________________________________________
Executed in   11.85 millis    fish           external
   usr time    0.55 millis  547.00 micros    0.00 millis
   sys time   11.36 millis  137.00 micros   11.22 millis

I assume that the issue is related to SSH configuration, but I cannot pinpoint the difference between the connections. I ensured that vscode uses the same configuration as when I connect manually, and I tried searching through vscode settings to see if anything overrides these settings and connect with extensions disable, no luck.
It also worth mentioning that it was working fine in the past and started randomly at some point. Maybe it is connected to changes on our server or an update in vscode or its extensions, but, again, I wasn't able to narrow it down.
Any ideas what could be causing this? Or how can I debug the problem?

I believe screen tries to parse your termcap. Try changing and/or inspecting the env var for TERM before starting screen. Both with and without starting a ssh session
